# Which RELEASE Certificates (Signing/Upload) to Set Up in Google API keys and Firebase Settings

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, certificate, api-key

While there were many related posts, I could not find an exact answer to my question.

I will create a separate Firebase project before we get the app to Production, but for now I'm trying to use a single Firebase project but separate google API keys for DEBUG and RELEASE.

For Android RELEASE builds, where does each SHA-1 fingerprint (signing vs upload) have to be entered?

I put *both* signing (from GooglePlay console) and upload (from keytool with RELEASE keystore) fingerprints in:

- `google-services.json` in app build
- Firebase project settings
- Google API key restrictions

I assume I need both because in the API key restrictions because I need the key to work regardless of whether the RELEASE build is uploaded directly to a test device or the build was downloaded from GooglePlay store.

I didn't think I needed the signing SHA-1 in `google-services.json` because I thought GooglePlay overwrites the SHA-1 with its own automatically, but other posts have mentioned needing the signing SHA-1 on Firebase settings as well, and adding it there updated the `google-services.json` file Firebase provides for download.

However, upon attempting anonymous login (with RELEASE build on a test device), the RELEASE build gives the error:

```
"Requests from this Android client application {package.name} are blocked."
```

Does the order I put the fingerprints in matter?  Should I have only put in one?  I previously only had the upload fingerprint, but it also didn't work.

Solution from related posts that I have tried to no avail:

- deleting and re-entering the fingerprints in Firebase

Works but not ideal:

- removing certificate restrictions in API key and making the API key unrestricted

Comment: You should be able to use the same SHA-1 among multiple apps. Each app needs to have a different package name. It's the combination of SHA-1 and package name that needs to be unique among all Firebase apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, adding the DEBUG certificate to the RELEASE API key restrictions (even though the google-services.json in RELEASE mode doesn't have it listed) is what works.

It seems deploying a RELEASE build to a device connected by USB inadvertently still uses the DEBUG certificate for signing.